# Pessimistic Lock with Update Query

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-update, jpql

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query updateQuery = session.createQuery("UPDATE Lot l SET l.currentRate = l.currentRate + 100, l.lastOwner = :lastowner WHERE l.id = :lotid", null);
        updateQuery.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

So, here is my code fragment. I got an exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting a SELECT query : `UPDATE Lot l SET l.currentRate = l.currentRate + 100, l.lastOwner = :lastowner WHERE l.id = :lotid`** when I try to call *setLockMode*.
Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: These actions execute in parallel threads.

Comment: It seems like pessimistic lock can work with only a select query. It was obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Java doc of the method you are trying to call: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setLockMode(javax.persistence.LockModeType)

It explicitly says, that an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown if you execute this on a non-SELECT statement.